# App is loading before dependencies requirejs get Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define()

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have the following externals dependencies on my webpack.config.prod.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        libraryTarget: 'amd',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        react: 'react',
        'react-dom': 'react-dom'
    },
};
module.exports = config;
```

and I have the following script on my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>React App</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js" crossorigin=""></script>
        <script>
          (function(cdn) {
            require(cdn);
            ['react', 'react-dom'].forEach(dep => (dep) => {
              define(dep, cdn, function(b) {
                return b[dep];
              });
            });
          })(['http://localhost:8080/public/bundle.js'])
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

as you can see I'm trying to load my react and react-dom dependencies from a cdn but the app.js is loading before dependencies so I'm getting:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module:
>   function(e,t){return function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return
>   t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return
>   e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,n),o.l=!0,o.exports}return
>   n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof
>   Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"**esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var
>   r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof
>   e)for(var o in e)n.d(r,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return
>   r},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return
>   e.default}:function(){return e};return
>   n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return
>   Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=2)}([function(t,n){t.exports=e},function(e,n){e.exports=t},function(e,t,n){"use
>   strict";n.r(t);var r=n(0),o=n.n(r),u=n(1),i=n.n(u);function
>   c(e){return(c="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof
>   Symbol.iterator?function(e){return typeof e}:function(e){return
>   e&&"function"==typeof
>   Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof
>   e})(e)}function f(e,t){for(var n=0;n||Object.getPrototypeOf(e)})(e)}function
>   p(e,t){return(p=Object.setPrototypeOf||function(e,t){return
>   e.proto**=t,e})(e,t)}var y=function(e){function t(){return
>   function(e,t){if(!(e instanceof t))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a
>   class as a function")}(this,t),a(this,l(t).apply(this,arguments))}var
>   n,r,u;return function(e,t){if("function"!=typeof t&&null!==t)throw new
>   TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a
>   function");e.prototype=Object.create(t&&t.prototype,{constructor:{value:e,writable:!0,configurable:!0}}),t&&p(e,t)}(t,o.a.Component),n=t,(r=[{key:"render",value:function(){return
>   o.a.createElement("div",null,"Hello
>   ",this.props.name)}}])&&f(n.prototype,r),u&&f(n,u),t}();i.a.render(o.a.createElement(y,{name:"Jean"}),document.getElementById("app"))}])}
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
>       at makeError (require.min.js:1)
>       at intakeDefines (require.min.js:1)
>       at require.min.js:1

How can I load app.js after dependencies?

Comment: https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html

Comment: @Ellone I already see this information but can't figure it out what's going on